# how to position absolute image inside div element

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have an image with absolute position image inside div tag. What i want to resize the div tag according to image if i resize the browser. My code are here:-

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    width:225px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="images/photo1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Actually div tag border doesn't containing an image which is absolute positioned.
Please help.

Comment: How do you want the image to sit within the div? In the center? At some offset? Fill the div with the image?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* you need to position the image with `position:absolute`?

Comment: @Danield yes i need it coz i have a slider which have absolute positioned image.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not well worded. But maybe you need something like this?:

```
#parent{
    width:100%;
    max-width:250px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

are you sure you need it absolute?